# Measure Induced by Integration

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, density-function

Consider a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$.

Let $f: (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ be a non-negative and mesurable. Then,
$$\nu({A})=\int_{{\Omega}} 1_{A}(x) f(x) d\mu$$ where $A \in \mathcal{F}$ defines a measure on $(\mathcal{F}, [0,\infty])$

show that if $\int_{\Omega} f(x) d\mu=1$, then $\nu(\Omega)=1$.

**POST:**
So, from the definition of $\nu$, we have
$$\nu({\Omega})=\int_{{\Omega}} 1_{\Omega}(x) f(x) d\mu=\int_{{\Omega}}  f(x) d\mu=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_\Omega f(x)dx=\int_\Omega 1_\Omega(x)f(x)dx$, because $1_\Omega(x)$ is the same as multiplying $f(x)$ by one on the entire domain of the integral.